# css3 - How to make this shape?

Tags: css, shapes, css-shapes

I am trying to use css3 to create this shape:

[image: simple shape]

(I know the image quality is terrible but you get the point). 
I 've tried some of these css shape generators:
http://medleyweb.com/resources/css-generator-ui-animation/
with no success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HKbrq

**HTML:**

```
<div class="trapezoid">  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.trapezoid {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 40px;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: black;
  border-left-width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with SVG ? you can draw polygons. SVG is XML-based.
Or use the matrix() transform.